# Regex expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex expression in C# which can remove any number of double quotes coming in my string, it is a csv file where after reading from StreamReader I want to replace all double quotes coming in my string. First row is header and second is data. For ex:

```
"E-mail","First Name","Last Name","Company"
"san@test.com","sanjay","sen","this is my "test" company"
```

So ideally regex should give following output :

```
"E-mail","First Name","Last Name","Company"
"san@test.com","sanjay","sen","this is my test company "
```

So double quotes removed from column `"this is my "test" company"` and resultant into `"this is my test company"`

Comment: Are you really getting invalid CSV files that has unescaped quotation marks? Also, what about the mismatched `"Company" san@test.com"`, how should that be treated?

Comment: Hi Guffa, Sorry I corrected the mismatched csv. I dont have much knowledge of regular experession so want help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to fix the source of improperly escaped strings instead of mucking around with a regex. If you can't do that and are desperate to get something done, one quick and dirty approach would be to remove quotes that don't border on commas or start/end of string:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, "(?<!,|^)\"(?!,|$)", "");
```

This assumes that you're handling one CSV row at a time. If you have the entire file in a single string, then use `RegexOptions.Multiline` as the third parameter.

Comment: Tim, it worked :-)
Many thanks for your quick help.

Answer (score 1):

As there should be some **whitespace characters** around commas, you should go with

```
output = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<!,\s*)\"(?!\s*,)", "");
```

---

CSV standard allows **double** double-quotes inside, such as `"this is a ""legal"" format"`.

To romove such quotes you should use

```
output = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<!,\s*)\"{2}(?!\s*,)", "");
```

Comment: Are you sure about whitespace around commas? For example, Python's CSV parser treats such whitespace as significant and makes it part of the field.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - The are part of field, if no quotes are used, for example line `12 , 34,  "56"  ,7` represents `12 ` with space behind, ` 34` with space in front, `56` with no spaces and `7` with no spaces. So spaces before and after quotes are ignored, if such item is quoted. Clear? :) OP's question is out of CSV standard, so... Anyway. You got credit. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Tim,
I am having issue if CSV having following data in it:
id,"First, Name","Captured, ""Status"" on page","Captured, ""Status"" on url"
It results into follwoing output after using regex given by you:

id,"First, Name","Captured, Status on page","Captured, Status on url


You can see "Captured, Status on url field missing the trailing double quote in output. Could you please modify your regex so I can get correct output